# v-html does not work with text from database

Tags: javascript, vue.js

Let's say I have these following code:

```
<template>
  <div>
    <div v-html="href1"></div>
    <div v-html="href2"></div>
  </div>
</template>
<script>
export default {
  data: function() {
return {
  href1: '<a href="https://google.com/">toGoogle</a>',
  href2: ''
}
},
beforeMount() {
 this.href2 = getHref2FromDB()
}

}
</script>
```

the getHref2FromDB() is just a method to get href2 from a database and the content is identical to href1.
Now, the problem is, if I actually run the code and console.log() these two data, they print

```
<a href="https://google.com/">toGoogle</a>
```

, but if I actually check the element of these two divs, href1 work perfectly and href2 will look like this:

```
<a href="https:  google.com ">toGoogle</a>
```

every single '/' is somehow translated to a space sign.
So to summarize, href2 from DB looks fine, console.log(href2) looks fine and even {{ href2 }} looks fine, only when I use it with v-html would it replace '/' with ' ' in href="" , whereas href1 works perfectly. Anyone got a clue?

Comment: perhaps `getHref2FromDB` is messing the value it returns, (looks like it's removing `/` ) or maybe even the server is replacing those `/` with spaces? can't tell, you didn't post the code that is clearly causing the issue

Comment: As I described, if I print out href2, it looks exactly like href1. And those / s are still there. Unfortunately I can not pinpoint the exact sopt that cause this problem. Thanks for the this remind.

Comment: Without the code for `getHref2FromDB`, nobody can answer this

Comment: `print out` ... .so even href1.length === href2.length ... or better `href1 === href2`

Comment: jesus christ... I found the answer, I exchanged all the " to ' in the database and it works fine now.

Answer (score -1):

Just make sure the html string in DataBase uses single quote to avoid this issue.